# Haskell- lists from root to leaves

Tags: haskell, tree

The code suppose to return a list of every path from a root to a leaf in the tree, in order from left to right. Nodes with one child (one `Tip` and one `Bin`) are not considered leaf nodes.

I tried to code like

```
paths :: Tree a -> [[a]]
paths Tip = [[]]
paths (Bin Tip x Tip) = [[x]]
paths (Bin left x right) = map (x:) (paths left ++ paths right)
```

But it seems return the path include nodes with one child. This will lead to paths like `[[4,3],[4]]` on `Bin (Bin Tip 3 Tip) 4 Tip`.

Comment: `[] :: [a]` is the empty list for *all* list types, including nested list types (where `a ~ [b]`).

Answer (score 7):

This is due to the fact that your `paths Tip = [[]]` returns a list with *one* element: an empty list.

This thus means that for a `Bin Tip 4 (Bin Tip 3 Tip)` for example, the `paths left` will thus return a `[[]]`, and you prepend that list with `4`, so `[4]` will be yielded as well.

If you change this to `paths Tip = []`, you fix the problem, since then it will not yield an element:

```
paths :: Tree a -> [[a]]
paths Tip = []
paths (Bin Tip x Tip) = [[x]]
paths (Bin left x right) = map (x:) (paths left ++ paths right)
```